# Why the validation message is not go away even values are same?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a registration form with jQuery form-validation. And validations is working properly for all fields.

I compared password and confirm password through 'equelTo' rules, but the message does not go away even the values are same.

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate my problem. [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/kaw3q1e6/1/)

```
$(function() {

  $("form[name='userRegistration']").validate({
    rules: {
      userEmail: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6
      },
      rePassword: {
       required: true,
        minlength: 6,
        equalTo: "#password"
      }
    },
    messages: {
      userEmail: "Please enter valid email address.",
      password: {
        required: "Please provide password",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long."
      },
      rePassword: {
        required: "Please provide confirm password",
        minlength: "Confirm password must be at least 6 characters long.",
        equalTo: "Enter Confirm Password Same as Password"
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Because your password field has an ID of `userPassword`, so it should be `equalTo: '#userPassword'`. Vote-to-close as typo.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, Please also upvote my question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If I'm voting to close your question as a trivial matter, I'm downvoting it. If I could, I'd downvote it again just because you asked me to upvote it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`equalTo: "#password"` vs. `id="userPassword"`

Double-checking the id's would have been my first choice in your case...

Comment: Yes, jp-jee. I checked there is `id` mismatched in my code. Thanks.